# Measurement and probability for quantum states

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises

Suppose that the physical system is in generic state $|\psi\rangle$. Show that $\sum_{\lambda}p^2_{\lambda} = 1$ to an observable $O$, if and only if $\Delta O = 0$. ($\Delta O$ is a standard deviation).

Using the probability measure definition $p_{\lambda} = \langle\psi|P_{\lambda}|\psi\rangle$. Using hypothesis, 
$$\sum_{\lambda}\langle\psi|P_{\lambda}|\psi\rangle^2 = 1,$$
the fact that $\sum_{\lambda}\langle\psi|P_{\lambda}|\psi\rangle = 1$ and the definition $\Delta O = \sqrt{\langle O^2\rangle - \langle O\rangle^2 }$.

I tried
$$\langle O^2\rangle - \langle O\rangle^2 = \langle\psi|O^2|\psi\rangle - (\sum_{\lambda}\lambda\langle\psi|P_{\lambda}|\psi\rangle)^2,$$
but dont know what else to do

Comment: What does "Show that $\sum_{\lambda}p^2_{\lambda} = 1$ to an observable $O$" mean?

Comment: $p_{\lambda}$ is a probability of obtaining the eigenvalue $\lambda$ than result of measurement of the observable $O$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume all the eigenvalues are distinct, or there will be some issues.

The standard deviation is zero, if and only if the probability is peaked at one value, i.e $p_i=1$ for a single of $i$ and zero for the others.(try to prove this )

Now if the probability is peaked at one value, it clearly implies that, $\Sigma_\lambda p_\lambda^2 = 1$

Therefore $\Delta O = 0$ implies $\Sigma_\lambda p_\lambda^2 = 1$

Now the other way.

Consider $ (\Sigma_\lambda p_\lambda)^2 - \Sigma_\lambda p_\lambda^2 = 0$. Since $p_\lambda \geq 0$, This equality implies only one of the $p_\lambda$'s are non zero. Therefore it is a peaked distributive, with $p_i = 1$ for a single $i$ and zero for the others. Therefore standard deviation is zero.

Therefore $\Sigma_\lambda p_\lambda^2 = 1$ implies that $\Delta O = 0$.

Comment: Thank by your reply, I dont understand Why $(\Sigma_\lambda p_\lambda)^2 - \Sigma_\lambda p_\lambda^2 = 0$ implies only one of the $p_{\lambda}$ are non zero. Resolving

$$(\Sigma_\lambda p_\lambda)^2 - \Sigma_\lambda p_\lambda^2 = 0 \iff \Sigma_\lambda p_\lambda^2 - \Sigma_\lambda p_\lambda^2 + 2(\lambda_1 \lambda_2 + \lambda_1 \lambda_3 + \cdots)=0$$

And $2(\lambda_1 \lambda_2 + \lambda_1 \lambda_3 + \cdots)$ never is zero

Comment: if 2  terms are non zero say $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$, then the 2 $\lambda_1$ $\lambda_2$ term will be greater than zero, thus causing a contradiction. However if all but one term is zero, then the $\Sigma \lambda_i$ $\lambda_j$(i not equal to j ) will be identically zero

Comment: I would like that you review this question http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/60351/unitary-operator-apply-to-entangled-vector?noredirect=1#comment121479_60351, please.